# How do I restart the labelling of enumerate for several questions?

Tags: lists, enumerate

Total newbie here ...

I'm trying to program an assignment with "Question 1" (header) followed by 5 sub questions in a list "(a),(b),(c)" and so on. I coded Question 1 and the sub questions correctly, but how do I reset the counter so that for the next "Question 2", it's not starting on (e) but starting on (a) again?

My initial thought process was to code

```
\end{enumerate}
```

at the end of Q1 and then simply do

```
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
```

before i begin Q2.

but this is bringing up a lot of errors for me, how do I fix this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome! Can you please post a minimal example showing what you've tried? The counter normally resets by default, so it is hard to know exactly what you've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counter resets by default. Additional work is required to prevent it doing so.

Hence, anything which ends the `enumerate` environment and then restarts it will do, whether that environment is nested in an enclosing list or not.

For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\arabic*]
  \item First one
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
    \item a
    \item b
    \item c
    \item d
    \item e
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Second two
  \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
    \item a
    \item b
    \item c
    \item d
    \item e
  \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\newlist{subqns}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[subqns]{label=(\alph*)}
\section{Question First of Two}
\begin{subqns}
  \item a
  \item b
  \item c
  \item d
  \item e
\end{subqns}
\section{Question Second of Two}
\begin{subqns}
  \item a
  \item b
  \item c
  \item d
  \item e
\end{subqns}
\end{document}
```

[image: default resets]